# Vector Floating Point Register VS Generic ARM Registers Which one is Faster?

Tags: floating-point, arm, cpu-registers

I was reading about VFP registers and the fact that compared to Scalar Based processors (or super scalar based processors such as intel x86)
But My question is a little bit more detailed.

I guess (just guess) that the VFP registers and Vector processors are doing it faster to calculate mathematical operation. But what if we are using it just to store values?

What is faster storing and reading a values of a register to a VFP register or storing/reading a value from general purpose arm registers?

*The reasoning behind asking this question (not really part of question):
You are probably thinking why would I do that? Because I am injecting some ARM assembly codes to an application to save some register values (specifically LR and FP) in an array. The problem for me is when I want to store this registers value to an array but first have to save them to some other general purpose registers (e.g. r8,r9,r10) and then point them to my array. But because my injected ARM assembly codes are in the middle of some functions, I must push and pop the stack to maintain the previous values on those registers (which is memory operation and slow down the entire application since my code get injected to every function in the application). So It came to my mind to use VFP registers to save the data and avoid push pop, since in my target application it is never being used. Is it right path or lame?*

Comment: It's only a guess without ARM official documentation, but, as soon as ARM pretends to be a RISC architecture and such copying occupies exactly a single instruction, it should not cost more than a copying between integer registers.

Comment: @Netch Thank you :P However in the wikipedia it mentioned that the VFP CPUs(or co-CPU) are faster than Scalar based CPUs. But I really have no idea.

Comment: Note that the 'vector' aspect of VFP is deprecated and unsupported on modern CPUs - it's really just a regular FPU. Also there is some confusion here between 'scalar' (vs. 'vector'/SIMD) and 'superscalar' (i.e. issuing >1 instruction per cycle), which are entirely different contexts and not directly related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rather depends on the microarchitecture involved, but in general you should probably consider transfers between registers (of any sort) and memory to be preferable to transfers directly between integer and VFP registers.

Modern ARM CPUs are designed to be really quite good at moving stuff between registers and memory - it's something they have to do rather a lot, so you'd expect it to be significantly optimised for. Unless you're in some atypical workload it's a reasonable assumption that the bottom of the stack is probably hot in the L1 cache, in which case you've only a couple of cycles latency to load from it (and stores will likely go straight into a write buffer, making latency there negligible).

Data transfer between the integer pipeline and the floating-point pipeline, on the other hand, is a lot less common. In the absolute worst case you'll take a fault, have to have the OS power up and enable the FPU then retry the instruction, all of which could easily be slower than a simple load/store missing completely in the caches and having to go all the way out to memory. Even in the best case there is typically a fairly significant latency, even to the point that (I am led to believe) on certain microarchitectures something like e.g.:

```
vmov r0, s0
```

may actually take *longer* to execute in total than the equivalent:

```
vstr s0, [sp]
vldr r0, [sp]
```

so if you only care about doing half that work (i.e. just moving the register contents *somewhere*) then hitting the stack could be by far the quickest option.

Like any performance question though, if in doubt, benchmark every option and pick whichever is the fastest in practice, with your code and data, on your target hardware.